# Type constraint between methods

Tags: typescript, generics

Is it possible to create class/object with type constraint between methods?

```
abstract class Test<T>{
  abstract method1(): T
  abstract method2 (arg: T):any
}
```

What I want is the argument of method2 to be the same type as the return type of method1 - if the type is different, I should get a type error. The type itself is not important.

I achieved this by using generic class, but I need to pass in the type in advance, which seems artificial and unnecessary to me.

1. Is there a way to do this without the need to specify the type in advance, or without generic class?
2. Side question - is it possible to refer to class and/or return type of another method? Something in the lines of `method2(arg: ReturnType<this.method1>):any` or `method2(arg: typeof this.method1):any`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Use `ReturnType<Test['method1']>` instead of `ReturnType<this.method1>`:

```
class RandomClass{
  methodX(): number {
    return 1;
  }
}

let randomFunction = function() : boolean {
  return true;
}

class TestClass{
  method1(): string {
    return '';
  };
  method2 (arg: ReturnType<TestClass['method1']>): any {
    return null;
  }
  method3 (arg: ReturnType<RandomClass['methodX']>): any {
    return null;
  }
  method4 (arg: ReturnType<typeof randomFunction>): any {
    return null;
  }
}

let test = new TestClass();

test.method2('asd'); // OK
test.method2(2); // TS compilation error. Expected string

test.method3(5); // OK
test.method3('asdf'); // TS compilation error. Expected number

test.method4(true); // OK
test.method4('asd'); // TS compilation error. Expected boolean
```

Check this code with the TS erros in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/type-constraint-between-methods).

**Note:** `ReturnType<>` is valid from TypeScript 2.8+.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is close to what I want but is this scenario possible? 
To have an abstract Base class, that require any other class that extend Base class to implement method1 and method2. And somehow in the Base class, "link" the return type of method1 and argument type of method2 together. Every child class can implement method1 and method2 differently with different types, but the "type link" between method1 and method2 must always be fullfilled.

Comment: Mako, I'm afraid you can't do that. When you mark a method as `abstract`, you need to implement it in derived class, and when you do that you're overriding whatever returning type is in your `abstract` method. The solution in this case would be implementing what I've suggested in each derived class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to be able to define linked pairs of functions for arbitrary `T`, otherwise you'd just write functions with concrete types, right? I think that any way you slice it, you need a generic type parameter somewhere, to tie the return type of the first function to the parameter of the second.

What about:

```
interface Linked<T> {
    (): T;
    method2: (arg: T) => any;
}

const method1String: Linked<string> = () => "foo";
method1String.method2 = arg => arg.length;
```

Trying it out, this has two nice properties:

- You get a compiler error if you don't have a method2 property.
- method2's argument type is correctly inferred, and you get a compiler error if you try to type it some other way.

That said, I think it'd be useful to know what the context is here. Presumably the functions are intended to be used together somehow, so what prevents you from simply constraining them this way?

```
function doSomethingWithLinkedFunctions<T>(function1: () => T, function2: (arg: T) => any) {
}
```

This has the advantage of not needing some clumsy data type, as well as being able to infer `T` from `function1`.

Another option, in case the pair of functions needs to stay together:

```
type Linked<T> = [() => T, (arg: T) => any];

function doSomething([func1, func2]: Linked<string>) {
}
```